# How can I get Automatically Refresh Views to work?

Tags: ios, objective-c, storyboard, interface-builder

My custom UIView is not triggering this to run, but other custom views I make trigger it. Does anyone know the reason that this automatic refreshing of views would be triggered? Or Why "Refresh All Views" is greyed out.

[image: greyedoutrefreshallviews]

Code is in here:
https://github.com/HannahCarney/HCRotaryWheel

Comment: Are you using IBDesignable/IBInspectable ?

Comment: Yes I am and in this particular case it will not refresh views

Answer (score 2):

- Make sure you have `IBInspectable` properties for your view. (like
  changing your view color,just to make sure your `IBDesignable` thing
  works).
- Make sure you have the code for your customisation in your view  .m

file. (in your view draw rect method).

- Make sure you provide the file owner name for your `IBDesignable` view.(in your storyboarD)
- Make sure you mention `IB_DESIGNABLE` on your view .h file.
- Finally a qucik clean and build of your storyboard,shall enable the
  option of  Refresh All views.

**Sample code:**

for view.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

IB_DESIGNABLE


@interface designalble_UIView : UIView

@property (nonatomic) IBInspectable UIColor *startColor;
@property (nonatomic) IBInspectable UIColor *midColor;
@property (nonatomic) IBInspectable UIColor *endColor;
@property (nonatomic) IBInspectable NSInteger borderWidth;
@property (nonatomic) IBInspectable CGFloat cornerRadious;
@property (nonatomic) IBInspectable BOOL isHorizontal;


@end
```

for view.m

```
#import "designalble_UIView.h"

@implementation designalble_UIView

- (instancetype)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame {
    self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
    if (self) {

        self.startColor     = [UIColor redColor];
        self.midColor       = [UIColor greenColor];
        self.endColor       = [UIColor blueColor];
        self.borderWidth    = 2;
        self.cornerRadious  = 10;
        self.isHorizontal   = NO;

        [self customInit];
    }
    return self;
}

- (id)initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)aDecoder {
    self = [super initWithCoder:aDecoder];
    if (self) {
        [self customInit];
    }
    return self;
}


- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect {
    [self customInit];
}

- (void)setNeedsLayout {
    [super setNeedsLayout];
    [self setNeedsDisplay];
}


- (void)prepareForInterfaceBuilder {

    [self customInit];
}

- (void)customInit {


    self.layer.cornerRadius = self.cornerRadious;
    self.layer.borderWidth = self.borderWidth;

    if (self.cornerRadious > 0) {
        self.layer.masksToBounds = YES;
    }


    CAGradientLayer *gradient = [CAGradientLayer layer];
    gradient.frame = self.bounds;

    gradient.colors = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:(id)[self.startColor CGColor],(id)[self.midColor CGColor], (id)[self.endColor CGColor], nil];
    gradient.endPoint = (self.isHorizontal) ? CGPointMake(1, 0) : CGPointMake(0, 1);
    [self.layer insertSublayer:gradient atIndex:0];

}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks so much for your response - sadly my code includes all of these things. The only way I can get those buttons to not be greyed out is if I put another of my custom views in, remove it and then put mine back in and click "Refresh All Views", but this custom view never triggers "Automatically Refresh Views". Since I have a significant amount of code I cannot post it all here but it's in there: https://github.com/HannahCarney/RotaryWheel

Comment: That should be a bug. You dont need to remove your custom view. Just change the file owner name in your storyboard which will enable the refres view option, and change the file owner name again back to HCLWheel view and click on refresh views.

Comment: Yeah that's what I have been doing to see the view in the storyboard, but because I'm trying to make this into a usable open source framework - it's not the perfect option.

Answer (score 1):

I solved this because I had put IB_DESIGNABLE in the wrong spot in my code:

I had a protocol at the top of my view and previously it looked like

```
IB_DESIGNABLE

@protocol RotaryProtocol <NSObject>

- (void) wheelDidChangeValue:(int)currentSector;
@end

@interface HCRotaryWheel : UIView

@property (weak) id <RotaryProtocol> delegate;
@property (nonatomic, strong) IBInspectable UIColor* background;

@end
```

To fix this I had to move IB_DESIGNABLE below protocol

```
@protocol RotaryProtocol <NSObject>

- (void) wheelDidChangeValue:(int)currentSector;
@end

IB_DESIGNABLE

@interface HCRotaryWheel : UIView

@property (weak) id <RotaryProtocol> delegate;
@property (nonatomic, strong) IBInspectable UIColor* background;

@end
```

Now my views refresh!!